# In functional derivative the starting point confusion

Tags: definition, notation, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

how can one define the functional derivative $$\delta F= F[f+\delta f]-F[f].$$
Is it by definition or any physical reason holds for it.

Comment: I think so. It seems like the generally how we can define a derivative, true?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "physical reason" - do you have a "physical reason" for why the ordinary derivative is $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$?

Answer (score 1):

That's not really the definition of the functional derivative. One way to define the functional derivative is
$$\frac{\delta F}{\delta f} (x_0) \equiv \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{\epsilon} (F[f+\epsilon \delta_{x_0}]-F[f]),$$
where $\delta_{x_0}$ denotes the Dirac delta function shifted to $x_0$, i.e. $\delta_{x_0} (x)\equiv \delta(x-x_0)$. So intuitively, the functional derivative $\delta F/\delta f$, evaluated at point $x_0$, measures how much the functional changes if we perturb the input function with a delta function at that point.

The convenience of this definition comes from the fact that I can find the leading order variation of the functional to any perturbation function $g$ by simply integrating over the functional derivative, i.e.
$$F[f+ \epsilon g]-F[f] = \epsilon\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx~ \frac{\delta F}{\delta f} (x) g(x) + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2).$$
For more details, I refer you to [these notes](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-981-10-2502-0%2F1.pdf), and also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3452417/437059).